# Looping through a specific set of Worksheets, then referencing cells from these worksheets in a separate mastersheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been stuck on this task for a while, hope someone can help!

I'm working on a macro to reference data from a number of separate tabs with company-specific information into a single master sheet. Some key points:

1. The number of companies will change (never above 200), so I want to loop through all worksheets except a specified range
2. Data in the company worksheets is brought in via an API, so for the data to appear in the master sheet I need to reference specific cells in the company worksheets
3. Data will be stored in a single column so, say, master sheet cells A2 downwards

**So basically I want code that can:**

- Reference cell A1 from Worksheet "Company 1" in the master sheet cell A2
- Reference cell A1 from Worksheet "Company 2" in the master sheet cell A3
  ...
- Reference cell A1 from Worksheet "Company X" in the master sheet cell AX+1
- Stop

Here is what I have so far...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim companies As Range
Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Mastersheet", "Conversions", "Dates")

Worksheets("Mastersheet").Activate
Set companies = Range("A2:A200")
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not (IsNumeric(Application.Match(ws.Name, arr, 0))) Then
     Worksheets("Daily Return").Activate
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Data From the Same Cell in Different Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    Dim Exceptions(): Exceptions = Array("Mastersheet", "Conversions", "Dates")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Mastersheet")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A2")
    
    dfCell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1).Clear
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            dfCell.Value = sws.Range("A1").Value
            'dfCell.Formula = "='" & sws.Name & "'!A1" ' !?
            Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next sws

    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```